# Excel VBA - Configurate MS Project Resource Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

All my data was prepared in Excel and my final step was transfer the data to MS Project. Before data been transfer, I am trying to edit table column in Resource Sheet. 
(Remove First 3 Default Column, Custom Text1 and add Text1 into position 1 at Resource Sheet)

-- Code Below was prepared in Excel --

```
Dim Proj    As MSProject.Application
Dim NewProj As MSProject.Project

Set Proj    = New MSProject.Application
Set NewProj = ActiveProject

'Activate Resource Sheet
Proj.ViewApply Name:="Resource Sheet", SinglePane:=True

'Custom Resource Text1 to From
Proj.CustomFieldRename FieldID:=pjCustomResourceText1, NewName:="From"

'Delete First 3 Default Column
Proj.ColumnDelete
Proj.ColumnDelete
Proj.ColumnDelete

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------
'THIS CODE NEED HELP - It didn't add column to Resource Sheet, 
' but add in Gantt Chart Sheet
Proj.TableEdit _
        Name:="Entry", TaskTable:=True, NewFieldName:="Text1", _
        Title:="From", Width:=6, Align:=1, _
        ShowInMenu:=True, LockFirstColumn:=True, DateFormat:=255, _
        RowHeight:=1, ColumnPosition:=1, AlignTitle:=pjCenter

Proj.TableApply Name:="Entry"
```

I am not sure what going on / Error coding, do you guy see any error.

Answer (score 0):

To edit a resource table (e.g. the Entry table for the Resource Sheet view), set the TaskTable argument of the TableEdit method to False:

```
Proj.TableEdit _
        Name:="Entry", TaskTable:=False, NewFieldName:="Text1", _
        Title:="From", Width:=6, Align:=1, _
        ShowInMenu:=True, LockFirstColumn:=True, DateFormat:=255, _
        RowHeight:=1, ColumnPosition:=1, AlignTitle:=pjCenter
```